# unir strings en una busqueda de Obiee 12?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, join, oracle-12c

hace poco entré en una empresa y estoy empezando a trabajar con "Oracle Business intelligence enterprise edition". Con la versión "Oracle Business Intelligence 12.2.1.4.0" para extraer la info de la base de datos. Yo nunca he trabajado con un software como este...

El caso es que estoy realizando una consulta entre dos áreas diferentes.

Una de ellas, me aporta valores numéricos, la otra me aporta etiquetas de 3 categorías diferentes. La columna que relaciona ambas áreas es la ID.

Es decir, esta ID en una area tiene una etiqueta y en la otra se le asocian valores numéricos.

Mi pregunta es, como puedo sumar los valores numéricos en función al valor de la columna de categoría?
Para representarlo todo, he combinado los valores numéricos con una columna creada con la función SUM(0), y para las etiquetas, con una columna creada como ''.

Obviamente, esto me muestra dos lineas para cada valor de ID, pues no se pueden sumar strings...

En el resultado, me gustaría obviar la columna de ID y que la query me muestre solo tres lineas, una de cada categoría y la suma total de los valores numéricos de cada una de ellas...

Espero haberme explicado..., Muchas gracias!